# How can I avoid an authentication dialog in Flex when using HTTPService or URLRequest?

Tags: apache-flex, rest, restful-authentication

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153420/is-it-feasible-to-create-a-rest-client-with-flex). I'm writing a Flex app (a WindowedApplication) that uses REST. Everything's fine when I post with valid authentication, but if I happen to pass an invalid username or password to the REST API (a Twitter REST API, to be specific), an authentication dialog pops up.

That's not a desirable user experience, and it happens both when I use HTTPService and URLRequest. There doesn't seem to be an event I can catch to cancel the dialog.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://twitter.com/statuses/update.json');
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    var encoder : Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();
    encoder.encode(this.user + ':' + this.password);
    request.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoder.toString()));
    var params:Object = new Object();
    params.status = msg;                
    request.data = params;

    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, HandleRequestComplete);
    loader.load(request);
```

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Twitter API Doc [here](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/REST+API+Documentation#Authentication):

> suppress_response_codes: If this
>   parameter is present, all responses
>   will be returned with a 200 OK status
>   code - even errors.  This parameter
>   exists to accommodate Flash and
>   JavaScript applications running in
>   browsers that intercept all non-200
>   responses.  If used, it's then the job
>   of the client to determine error
>   states by parsing the response body. 
>   Use with caution, as those error
>   messages may change.

Answer (score 2):

That is becouse your URLRequest is handling authentication. To avoid that do the next:

```
request.authenticate = false;
```

Regards!

Alain.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works in a normal Flex app, but in AIR applications you can set a list of allowed response codes to be considered valid.