# Flex -- C++ connection?

Tags: c++, apache-flex, programming-languages, cross-language

How do I connect a Flex Application( Internet Site ) and C++ togehter ?

a minimalistic example from what i mean (User Story):
Frank goes to www.myflexsite.de there are 2 textboxes and 1 Button( Label = add two numbers) .
He inserts 2 in the first textbox and 5 in the ohter. Now he clicks on the add button.

The Backend : We have a add.cpp file where an add method is defined :

```
int add(int a, int b ) ...
```

After Frank clicked on the  "add two numbers" Button the add-method in the C++ file is called and the result will be returned.An Alert Window with the result appears.

This is what i want to accomplish, but i don't know how i build the bridge between these 2 Languages.
**How can they communicate ?**

Comment: well.. it is a minimalistic example to reduce the complexity of my Problem. real world application : An Image Manipulation and Clustering with images.

Comment: I know you can run java apps on the web server and tie into to those, I would assume you can do the same with C++, maybe start looking at what you need to do for java and see if you can adapt it. I wish I could give you more info, but I've always used simple http services to connect remotely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be to write a small console application in C++ and then invoke it via Apache or any other web server using CGI. There are performance problems with this but it's a good start, and then you can move forward. From Flex just make HTTP requests and let your program parse them - for instance, you can send XML back and forth.

Comment: +1.  After the clarifications above, he can probably even skip the XML wrapper.  The caller can probably send the request as a GET request, and the C++ program will just send back the image, Content-Type: image/png or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is necessarily the intent, but depending on what you want to accomplish you may want to take a look at the Alchemy project - http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/  you can use it to compile C++ code down into code that runs on the Flash Player.

This won't help you communicate between a client and a server, but if there is code you don't want to have to completely rewrite that might be more helpful exposed directly in Flash, this could be a solution.

=Ryan ryan@adobe.com

Answer (score 0):

I was going to write a 'Restful' example, but a quick Bing search finds this guy has already done it:

[Yahoo! Image Search REST API - Flex example](http://www.prayank.net/flexblog/index.php/2007/06/20/flex-yahoo-rest-api-sample/)

Just write your own server side web api in whatever language floats your boat.

ETA: question [153420](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153420/is-it-feasible-to-create-a-rest-client-with-flex) might be helpful also.