# Flex GUI for C++ application, how to do it?

Tags: c++, user-interface, flex3

What is the method to create a **flex GUI** for a **c++** API and connect them? what is the procedure to do that? 
If any one can give me a *helloworld example* or some *example* it would be very easy to understand!!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. What do you mean by a GUI for an API?

Comment: Typically APIs don't have GUIs -- apps with GUIs use APIs...

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you're looking for:
http://pradeek.blogspot.com/2009/06/getting-started-with-alchemy-hello.html

or perhaps you're trying to do what this other SO user wanted:
[Flex -- C++ connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120082/flex-c-connection)