# How to send PUT HTTP Request in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, xmlhttprequest

I want to send HTTP PUT Request on one URL to update that content of XML via using API.

URL is like this: https://domainname.com/someurls/id.xml

I want to update that content.

But When I am sending this PUT request, I have seen that in Network Monitor of Flex 4, Its going as the POST request on this web, while I am setting method as PUT in HTTPService variable.

So I am getting error.
So is there any way to send the PUT request on the web ?
Or
Is there any special header to set PUT method ?
I have tried method header but its not working....

Please help me.....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found the solution to send the put and delete service with HTTPSerivce in flex.

You just have to send one more header with the service method POST.

You have to send data in the POST method and attach one more header X-HTTP-Method-Override and the value as the PUT or DELETE.

Your service will be send as PUT or DELETE.

Thanks......

Comment: One should be a little more cautious in using the phrase "the solution".  This method depends on the server actually supporting this custom header, which was introduced by Google and MS some years ago (http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/2.0/basics.html#UpdatingEntry).  Still, +1, since this is useful in those cases that it is supported (eg, yours ;).

Comment: Does Amazon S3 support X-HTTP-Method-Override?

Answer (score 2):

While Mitul's response did work for me as well, I was able to get PUT and DELETE requests working by doing the following.

```
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            var urlString:String = "https://www.google.com/arbitraryUrl.json";
            var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlString);
            urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

            var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
            variables._method = "DELETE";
            urlRequest.data = variables;

            urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
```

So same concept really. Different way of going about it. Hope this helps some people.

Comment: But are you really talking about Flash in the web browser or Adobe Air ?

Answer (score 1):

Flex doesn't support `PUT` due to the underlying flash player. See [this article](http://verveguy.blogspot.com/2008/07/truth-about-flex-httpservice.html) about the limitations.

There is a [workaround here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153420/is-it-feasible-to-create-a-rest-client-with-flex#153589). However, if both the server and the client are under your control, I'd suggest using only `GET` and `POST`. Flex just isn't meant for true RESTful clients. (For example make a post with a parameter `put=true`)

Comment: +1 not supported. Though I'm pretty sure this is actually a browser limitation, not directly the fault of Flash Player.

Comment: well, I don't know about that. The browser does support PUT. And for example, I think a Java applet can use PUT.

Comment: Not all browsers support PUT/DELETE, certainly modern browsers have support for this stuff, but not all older browsers do. Silverlight had the same restriction, at least it the first 2 releases, (I'm not sure about now, I think they may have worked around it.) I'm not familiar with enough Java Applets though.

Either way, we will all be far better off when we have proper support for this.

Comment: well, it is not that hard to implement it after all. HTTP is a simple protocol.

Comment: Yah, I have already found that....
I have found on the same site...
but thanks for reply......

Thanks you very much....

Comment: @Bozho : but then you don’t use the browser stack which prevent sending Javascript cookies.