# Does Flex 4 support put request?

Tags: apache-flex, flash

Does Flex 4 support put request?

I know that Silverlight 4 support put request using its client http stack.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send PUT HTTP Request in Flex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641148/how-to-send-put-http-request-in-flex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In action script 3 we can use put method using below API

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLRequestMethod.html

I have used it on desktop apps to upload images to Amazon S3.
Since it need air it can be used only on desktop and not on web apps.

Answer (score -1):

yes, it does.
You have to set the 'method' attribute to "PUT".

i.e.:

```
s:HTTPRequest id="someID" method="PUT" ...
```

For more information have look on the Reference-Lib