# Http POST body in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, http, rest

Is there any way that I can set message body using POST/PUT HTTP methods in flex? or using REST with Flex in Browser ? Please help

```
PUT http://myurl:1234/myapi/changename

Accept: application/xml
Content-Type: application/xml

<SpecialService xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SessionId>guid of session</SessionId>
   <UserName>ABC</UserName>
   <NewServiceName>My service xs</NewServiceName>
</SpecialService >
```

Answer (score 1):

In theory, flex doesn't support PUT or DELETE requests, but you can try "X-HTTP-Method-Override".

```
request.requestHeaders = [new URLRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "PUT")];
```

Have a look on the following:
[RESTful PUT/DELETE with AS3 using X-HTTP-Method-Override](http://cambiatablog.wordpress.com/2010/08/10/287/)

similar question:[How to send PUT HTTP Request in Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641148/how-to-send-put-http-request-in-flex)