# Uploading Azure blobs using rest api

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am using signed urls to upload blobs from mobile devices using Air.

I have two questions:

When uploading blobs using a signed URL I assume I don't need to include all the headers as described in the documentation. Am I right in thinking that I simply need to do a `PUT` request to the URL and include the file encoded into the body with the `Content-Type` set to `multipart/form-data; boundary=[[boundary here]]`?

```
var client:HttpClient = new HttpClient();
var request:HttpRequest = new Put();
request.body =  UploaderPostHelper.getPostData( filename,  byteArray);
request.contentType = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + UploaderPostHelper.getBoundary();
client.request(new URI(signedUrl), request);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179451.aspx

(Source code for UploadPostHelper is here https://code.google.com/p/as3asclublib/source/browse/trunk/net/UploadPostHelper.as)

And secondly, can I specify that I want to do a PUT request using a POST request and a header?

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When uploading blobs using a signed URL I assume I don't need to
>   include all the headers as described in the documentation.

You would need to specify 2 headers - `Content-Length` and `x-ms-blob-type`. I'm assuming you're saving the files as block blobs so the value for `x-ms-blob-type` should be `BlockBlob`.

Also the `Content-Type` should be the content type of the file e.g. `plain/txt`, `image/gif` etc.

> And secondly, can I specify that I want to do a PUT request using a
>   POST request and a header?

Not sure about this one. The `HTTP` method of your request should be `PUT`.

Comment: Ok cheers, the issue is that from ActionScript / Air, you can only do GET or POST methods unless you use 3rd party libraries which are buggy and not well maintained.

Comment: I didn't know about it. I just did a quick search and landed on this question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641148/how-to-send-put-http-request-in-flex. See if the answer there helps you.

Answer (score 2):

x-ms-version, Authorization, Date or x-ms-date, Content-Length and x-ms-blob-type are all required for the PUT operation. Content-Type is optional.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179451.aspx.