# How to create Simple web service

Tags: java, android, iphone, web-services

How to create simple web service that can be used by Mobile application (Android/iPhone Apps) using java.

Please suggest the solution.

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993900/how-to-create-a-web-service

Answer (score 6):

The most simple web service in Java would be basically any class annotated with `@Webservice` and published via the `Endpoint` class.

As an example, an implementation that echo's a String:

```
@WebService
public class EchoService {

    public String echoHello(String name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }

}
```

You can publish that on localhost via:

```
EchoService service = new EchoService();    
Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:2000/echo", service);
```

This will publish a SOAP endpoint with document/literal binding. For more information, see [the JAX-WS tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXWS.html).